# How to get html template of an Angular 2 Component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple angular 2 component:

> ```
> @Component({
>   selector: 'test-text',
>   template: `<p> Text </p>`
> })
> export class TestComponent {
>   constructor() {}      
>   getHtmlContent() {return;} //This should return '<p> Text </p>' as a string
> }
> ```

What is the simplest way I can the html content for my Component back?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `ElementRef`. E.g.

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test-text',
  template: `<p> Text </p>`
})
export class TestComponent {
  elRef: ElementRef

  constructor(elRef: ElementRef) {
    this.elRef = elRef;
  }      

  getHtmlContent() {
    //This will return '<p> Text </p>' as a string
    return this.elRef.nativeElement.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

Comment: This gives you DOM-translated html, which excludes all bindings. It does not give you the actual `component.template`

Comment: @allenhwkim This answer shows how you can get the component.template: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497561/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-html-template-for-an-angular-component#answer-45499616