# Retrieve the HTML from an imported component

Tags: angular, ionic2

Is there a way to retrieve the HTML from a imported component in Ionic2/Angular2?

So, for example:

```
import {A} from '../../components/a/a';

console.log(A.html());
```

Something similar to this - obviously there is no html method attached to the component here but I'm after something similar.

Comment: `ViewChild` or `ViewChildren` to the rescue

Answer (score 2):

I've never done that, but if I had to do it, it'd be something like this

```
import { A } from './a';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

// ...
@ViewChild('A') a: A;
```

Then I guess, in that variable, you could retrieve your HTML.

Comment: In order for that to work, `A` has to be part of the view.

Comment: true. But I wonder if you don't use ViewChild, maybe you can just have it as a simple variable ?

Comment: No, that wont work. That will not return html template as far as I know.

Comment: But maybe there's a property in the object to get it ?

Comment: @Faisal So there's no way at all to get the HTML of a component?

Comment: there is, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45499616/1791913