# Access angular component meta-data

Tags: javascript, angular, reflection, jasmine

is it possible to get the value of e.g. `changeDetection` attribute defined as part of a given component's decoration?

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-banner',
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class BannerComponent { }
```

i've tried:

```
Reflect.getMetadataKeys(BannerComponent) // []
Reflect.getOwnMetadataKeys(BannerComponent) // []
Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', BannerComponent) // undefined
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/VXfcZH9BWPWbdyBOJRTV?p=preview

Comment: n.b. we're using angular v5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47453704/115466

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly *hacky* but nevertherless a solution:

```
BannerComponent['__annotations__'][0]
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/HAbomBljAACHVz6N33m5?p=preview

Credits [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47453704/115466).

Comment: ng14+ use reflectComponentType() ... ng 13- use this answer